# SymbolSource Authentication

Tags: c#, nuget, symbols, debug-symbols

I'm writing a package for .NET which I'd like to share on Nuget.org as well as SymbolSource.org. I was able to push to Nuget just fine, but I can't for the life of me push to SymbolSource. I keep getting the following error message:

**Pushing MyPackage #.#.#.# to the symbol server (http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet)...**

> Failed to process request. 'Failed to verify permissions for upload:  Project NuGet/MyPackage not found or inaccessible for Public/SomeLongGuidString.
>   See http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/Help for possible reasons. Fiddler may help diagnosing this error if your client discards attached detailed information.'.
>   The remote server returned an error: (418) Failed to verify permissions for upload:  Project NuGet/MyPackage not found or inaccessible for Public/SomeLongGuidString.
>   See http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/Help for possible reasons. Fiddler may help diagnosing this error if your client discards attached detailed information...

Where "MyPackage", "#.#.#.#", and "SomeLongGuidString" are all obviously fake. One thing I've done recently which may be having an effect here is that I changed the title of my package recently to match its ID (apparently they haven't been the same this whole time, so I wanted to fix that--I gotta say, there are a lot of little things to worry about when trying to work with Nuget/SymbolSource, I hope they simplify this over time). I did this by changing the AssemblyTitle and AssemblyProduct attributes in AssemblyInfo.cs and repackaging with "nuget pack ...", and repushing to Nuget.org worked fine as I said.

On the SymbolSource.org site, I've created an account and tried going to the "Authenticate" page, but the interface is pretty obtuse: there's a table with three columns ("TYPE", "VALUE", "ACTION") and I can only seemingly add rows of TYPE "NuGet" since that's the only choice available in the dropdown. I have no idea then what to put for VALUE. I've tried my NuGet.org username, password, and API key, none of which worked. What am I missing?

Also, but unrelated: can someone with a higher reputation create a "symbol-source" tag so I can actually cite it in my "Tags" section?

Comment: I should also add that pushing to SymbolSource worked before the title change operation.

Answer (score 1):

I will need to ask you to at least post the actual package ID and version, and your user name (I assume it is gzak on both sites) to help diagnosing this. This might be a bug, or a misconfiguration of some sort, but it's impossible to tell from the info you provided. You can also contact support at symbolsource@symbolsource.org or post to our Google Group at http://groups.google.com/group/symbolsource.

In any case a change to package metadata (other than its ID) should not affect publishing in any way.

You don't need to create an account on symbolsource.org to just push, but you do need to use the same API key as for nuget.org. During a submission, nuget.org is contacted to verify permissions for posting with a given package ID. I can only guess that this is the step that failed, whatever the reason was.

If you create an account on symbolsource.org, you can then manage all your submissions through the web UI - e.g. delete stuff. For that you need to enter your API key in Authentication. This will also claim all packages you've submitted to symbolsource.org before creating an account.

Comment: Correct, I use "gzak" on both sites, and I only have one package, Unity.Mvc.Wcf.

Thanks for following up. In the time since I posted, I've updated both the package itself and the corresponding symbols, and it ended up working. One thing I think may have contributed to the ordeal is that I've been trying to post Release builds of my package to NuGet, but Debug builds to SymbolSource. This isn't really something supported yet by nuget.exe, so what I was doing was rather unorthodox.

At any rate, things are working now, but feel free to take a look at my account for insights.